# Encrypted RDS copy failure across region in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-rds, boto3, aws-cli

I have a script that copied the unencrypted and encrypted snapshots across regions.
Script is working fine with unencrypted snapshot copy but for some reason, encrypted copy is failing with an error:-

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CopyDBSnapshot operation: PreSignedUrl could not be authenticated.
```

Here is the code that I am using to copy encrypted snapshots

```
aws rds copy-db-snapshot 
--source-db-snapshot-identifier $source_identifier \
--target-db-snapshot-identifier ${target_identifier} \
--kms-key-id $Enc_Key_ID\ 
--region $target_region 
--source-region $source_region \
--tags Key="owner",Value="RDS Copy Job"
```

All variable passed here (Except for Encryption key )is working fine with the unencrypted copy across regions.

I wonder what is going wrong.Any help and suggestion would be a great help for me. 
(update)

```
aws rds copy-db-snapshot \
--source-db-snapshot-identifier arn:aws:rds:us-west-1:717934610271:snapshot:rds:rds-snapshot‌​-name-dev-2017-12-22‌​-08-08 \
--target-db-snapshot-identifier test-rds-snapshotname \
--kms-key-id XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX \
--region us-east-1\
--source-region us-west-1 \
--tags Key="owner",Value="RDS Copy Job"
```

Above is the full command that is used to copy. I am using ARN to copy

Answer (score 5):

Specify a KMS Key that is valid in the destination region.

> You can copy a snapshot that has been encrypted using an AWS KMS
>   encryption key. If you copy an encrypted snapshot, the copy of the
>   snapshot must also be encrypted. If you copy an encrypted snapshot
>   within the same AWS Region, you can encrypt the copy with the same KMS
>   encryption key as the original snapshot, or you can specify a
>   different KMS encryption key. **If you copy an encrypted snapshot across
>   regions, you can't use the same KMS encryption key for the copy as
>   used for the source snapshot, because KMS keys are region-specific.**
>   Instead, you must specify a KMS key valid in the destination AWS
>   Region.

[Handling Encryption](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CopySnapshot.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input John, I have gone through this document serval time and I have checked serval times hat those keys are valid for that particular region.

Comment: Make sure that you are using the ARNs for your parameters. If you still have problems post the full command that you are using putting a few XXXs in key parameters values.

Comment: `aws rds copy-db-snapshot --source-db-snapshot-identifier arn:aws:rds:us-west-1:717934610271:snapshot:rds:rds-snapshot-name-dev-2017-12-22-08-08 --target-db-snapshot-identifier test-rds-snapshotname --kms-key-id XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX --region us-east-1 --source-region us-west-1 --tags Key="owner",Value="RDS Copy Job"`

Comment: Above is the full command that is used to copy. I am using ARN to copy.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What was the solution here? We are facing similar sort of issue.

Comment: @vivekyad4v - I recommend creating a new question with your specific details.

Answer (score 2):

Below script worked for me, the idea is if KMS default key is not created in target AWS region than use kms ID `alias/aws/rds`, it will create the new KMS id.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    echo "please input source region from which copy"
    exit
fi
if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
    echo "please input destination region"
    exit
fi
REGION_SOURCE=$1
REGION_DESTINATION=$2
RDS_DBSnapshotIdentifier=`/usr/bin/aws rds describe-db-snapshots --region $REGION_SOURCE --query="reverse(sort_by(DBSnapshots, &SnapshotCreateTime))[0]" | /usr/bin/jq -r '.DBSnapshotArn'`
echo "Copying RDS from $REGION_SOURCE to $REGION_DESTINATION"
TODAY_DATE=`/bin/date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"`

KMS_KEY_ID=`/usr/bin/aws kms list-aliases --region $REGION_DESTINATION| /usr/bin/jq  -r '.[]' | /usr/bin/jq -r '.[] | select( .AliasName == "alias/aws/rds")' | /usr/bin/jq -r '.TargetKeyId'`
if [[ $KMS_KEY_ID == null ]]; then
   KMS_KEY_ID="alias/aws/rds"
fi

/usr/bin/aws rds copy-db-snapshot --kms-key-id $KMS_KEY_ID --source-db-snapshot-identifier $RDS_DBSnapshotIdentifier  --target-db-snapshot-identifier "RDS-COPY-${TODAY_DATE}-from-${REGION_SOURCE}-to-${REGION_DESTINATION}"  --region $REGION_DESTINATION  --source-region $REGION_SOURCE
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that `--source-region` parameter was necessary to provide when you copy encrypted snapshots. Here is the working CLI command -

```
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-south-1
source_snapshot_arn="arn:aws:rds:ap-southeast-1:3621xxxx334:snapshot:v2db-snapshot-1"
dest_snapshot_id="v2db-snapshot-1"

aws rds copy-db-snapshot \
  --kms-key-id db-prod-kms \
  --source-region ap-southeast-1 \
  --source-db-snapshot-identifier $source_snapshot_arn \
  --target-db-snapshot-identifier $dest_snapshot_id
```

Working KMS key policy -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-consolepolicy-3",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow backup to use  key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::3621xxxx8334:user/backup"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:CreateGrant",
                "kms:Create*",
                "kms:Describe*",
                "kms:List*",
                "kms:Get*",
                "kms:ImportKeyMaterial",
                "kms:TagResource",
                "kms:UntagResource"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
     ]
   }
```

Comment: Thank you! Using `--source-region` was the key for me :)